# What do you call the cut used to trick the audience into thinking the subjects of the scene haven’t changed?

Tags: editing

There’s a type of cut in a movie between scenes which is set up to temporarily trick the audience into thinking the subjects of the scene haven’t changed. For example a group of characters discuss getting breakfast and it cuts to a frying pan with sizzling eggs and the audience thinks “oh great we moved forward in time and they are getting breakfast” but then it quickly zooms out to show its a completely different group of characters. It’s often played for a quick funny moment but I suppose it could also be used to shock. It’s a kind of parallel editing I suppose but does the type of cut have a particular name?